# Why is the edit link displayed but is uneditable?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

Recently returned to active participation in Ask Different so bear with me if rules have changed.

Saw this post [Restoring a jailbroken iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80135/help-i-need-help-here) which IMO needed editing.
Though the edit link is displayed, it's unclickable. Only share is allowed.

Why?

Comment: Interesting.. The 'edit' option is disabled on this question as well (not that I was going to edit it). Have they just disabled it?

Comment: Possible Duplicate:  http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/999/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-link-below-the-post-on-this-page

Comment: Daniel, it's a duplicate but Mark's answer is better (concise and helpful). Possible to merge both questions for future reference?

Comment: @Phorce It says "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites" when you hover it on meta, so I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question had a pending edit by a user with low reputation (<2000). This has to be approved by two users with reputation >=2000.

As both @Globalnomad and @Phorce have < 2000 you cannot edit or approve it so you have to wait until the pending edit is approved. (I have approved it so only one more needed now)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for answering. Much appreciated.

Comment: I've cleared the edit queue, so @Globalnomad or others can fix it the rest of the way.